# Clone and modify Woocommerce Products catalog

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

My main problem is that my theme ( Avada ) is jumping from 6 columns to 1 which is a poor responsiveness, in Shop page. So, when I am in a vertical tablet, I just see 1 columns, when I could display 2-3 columns easily.

So, I downloaded [Fusion Builder Mobile Layout Creator](https://codecanyon.net/item/fusion-builder-mobile-layout-creator/19125174?_ga=1.131889615.1970487489.1482715851) that allows me to get one more responsive level ( between 400 and 800px )

Now, my problem is that I have to create a new Shop page, and modify it to display only 3 columns...

Thing is the shop page is not a normal page, so I don't really know how to do this.

Once I find it out, I guess it will not be so complicated modifying the code so that it displays in a custom columns layout

Also, this is outside scope of both Avada support and FBMLC support, so... here am I !!!

Comment: Sounds like you just need to make a child theme and then create your own hooks for WooCommerce and templates. Avada most likely has a custom hook to override WooCommerce defaults.

Comment: create a child is ok. Do you have some links talking about woocommerce hooks, as I don't know much about it...

Comment: I have created my child theme, but doesn't really know what to do now....